# Make browser window remain at same point when concatenating items to list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items rendered in React. There is a maximum number of items that the list will load at once and if the total number of items exceeds that amount there will be a "Load more" button. Clicking the button will cause the next few items to be appended to what is already being displayed. My issue is that when the "Load more" button is clicked, the browser window stays at the bottom of the (new) list. I would like the browser window to remain at the point in the list where the "Load more" button is clicked so the user must scroll down through the newly-loaded items before reaching the new "Load more" button. How do I achieve this?

Note: It appears that the browser window stays in place like I want it to when the final page of items is reached i.e. there are no more "Load more" buttons to be displayed. I'm yet to figure out why this is.

Here is my code:

```
// Load requirements
import React, {useEffect, useState}  from 'react'

import {apiTweetList} from './lookup'

import {Tweet} from './detail'


// Define the list of tweets included in the feed
export function TweetsList(props) {
    const [tweetsInit, setTweetsInit] = useState([])
    const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([])
    const [nextUrl, setNextUrl] = useState(null)
    const [tweetsDidSet, setTweetsDidSet] = useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
      const final = [...props.newTweets].concat(tweetsInit)
      if (final.length !== tweets.length) {
        setTweets(final)
      }
    }, [props.newTweets, tweets, tweetsInit])

    useEffect(() => {
      if (tweetsDidSet === false){
        const handleTweetListLookup = (response, status) => {
          if (status === 200){
            setNextUrl(response.next)
            setTweetsInit(response.results)
            setTweetsDidSet(true)
          } else {
            alert("There was an error")
          }
        }
        apiTweetList(props.username, handleTweetListLookup)
      }
    }, [tweetsInit, tweetsDidSet, setTweetsDidSet, props.username])

    const handleLoadNext = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (nextUrl !== null) {
        const handleLoadNextResponse = (response, status) =>{
          if (status === 200){
            setNextUrl(response.next)
            const newTweets = [...tweets].concat(response.results)
            setTweetsInit(newTweets)
            setTweets(newTweets)
          } else {
            alert("There was an error")
          }
        }
        apiTweetList(props.username, handleLoadNextResponse, nextUrl)
      }
    }

    return <React.Fragment>{tweets.map((item, index)=>{
      return <Tweet  
        tweet={item} 

        // Handle the styling of tweets
        className='py-5 border bg-white text-dark min-vh-100 scrollsnap-section' 
        key={`${index}-{item.id}`} />
    })}

    {/* Render the "load next" button */}
    {nextUrl !== null && <div class='scrollsnap-section'><button onClick={handleLoadNext} className='btn btn-outline-primary'>Load next</button></div>}
    </React.Fragment>
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window's scroll properties.
You can save scrollTop into a variable.
And when you concat to list, you can scroll on the previous location using this variable.

Comment: I was able to use the following code under "const handleLoadNext = (event) => {":
`const scrollPosition = document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container').scrollTop
        document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container').scrollTo(0, scrollPosition-50)`

For some reason it worked when I used "scrollPosition-32" or lower, so "scrollPosition-31" or "scrollPosition" by itself wouldn't work. I am yet to figure out why this is. The list is situated in a class called "scrollsnap-container" and utilizes scroll-snapping; maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I thought there is padding in scroll snap-container or there is something after the comment list. Which is taking space, that why you need to minus that  height.